# `os.system` not able to find file created by `with open` and read by `with open`

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, cmd, appdata

In a Python3 program running in Windows 10, `os.system()` is not able to find a file created in the `APPDATA` directory using `with open`, even after that same file can be successfully read by a subsequent `with open`.

**QUESTION FOR THIS OP:**

> What specific syntax needs to be changed in the Python3 code below in order to successfully create a file in the `APPDATA` directory that can be found visually by users of the Windows 10 Explorer UI and also programmatically by the `os.system()` command below which is failing?

**CURRENT CODE:**

The following code is what we are currently trying:

```
print(os.getenv('APPDATA'))
terraformRC = os.path.join( os.getenv('APPDATA'), "terraform.rc")
print("terraformRC is: ", terraformRC)
print("About to write terraformRC. ")
try: 
  with open(terraformRC, 'w') as f:
    f.write('provider_installation {\n')
    f.write('  filesystem_mirror {\n')
    f.write('    path    = "' + providersPath + '"\n')
    f.write('    include = ["*/*"]\n')
    f.write('  }\n')
    f.write('\n')
    f.write('  direct {\n')
    f.write('    exclude = ["*/*"]\n')
    f.write('  }\n')
    f.write('}\n')
except (Exception) as e:
  print(e)

print("About to read the terraformRC we just wrote.  ")
with open(terraformRC, 'r') as lines:
  for line in lines:
    print(line)

print("About to disable settings for folder so that the terraformRC file can be unhidden.  ")
removeSettingsCmd = 'attrib -h -s ' + terraformRC
os.system(removeSettingsCmd)
```

**CURRENT FAILED RESULTS:**

The following output is printed by Windows CMD when we call the above Python3 code from Windows CMD.

```
C:\path\to\AppData\Roaming
terraformRC is:  C:\path\to\AppData\Roaming\terraform.rc
About to write terraformRC.
About to read the terraformRC we just wrote.
provider_installation {
  filesystem_mirror {
    path    = "C:\path\to\dependencies\terraform\providers"
    include = ["*/*"]
  }
  direct {
    exclude = ["*/*"]
  }
}

About to disable settings for folder so that the terraformRC file can be unhidden.
File not found - C:\path\to\AppData\Roaming\terraform.rc
```

**THE PROBLEM:**

As you can see from the output above, Python seems to successfully find the `APPDATA` directory.  Then Python seems to successfully write a terraformRC file to `APPDATA`.  Then Python seems to successfully read the terraformRC file that it just seems to have written to `APPDATA`.

The problem is that the `os.system(removeSettingsCmd)` then fails with a message `File not found - C:\path\to\AppData\Roaming\terraform.rc` stating that it cannot find the terraformRC file at the correct location.  And also, a human user is not able to view the terraformRC file when looking for it in `APPDATA` using Windows Explorer.

Comment: @lit: No, that's not relevant.

Comment: What happens if you try to manually enter the `attrib` command for the file on the command line?

Comment: I think you may need quotes around the filename: ```removeSettingsCmd = 'attrib -h -s "' + terraformRC + '"'```

Comment: That's only a possibility of the real filenpath has any space characters in it.

Comment: @martineau it's obvious that `path\to\AppData` is completely made up, so the actual file name might have a space.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Yes, obviously, I didn't say anything contrary to that — in fact, just the opposite.

Comment: This question looks nearly identical to one that was posted a couple of days ago.  I was unable to reproduce it.

Comment: The error message apparently includes the full file path, which implies that it's not a space issue.  However, the reported output includes an extra space in the `terraformRC is:`, so the reported output is maybe suspect.

Comment: @jamesdlin: The path in the error message was probably changed to match the rest of the question. As are all the other things containing it (so there might even be an extra space which proves nothing).

Comment: @CodeMed I don't know what your point is.  I meant that that `print` call contains only one space after the colon, yet the reported output contains two spaces, which is impossible.  So the (obviously doctored) output doesn't match the code and seems untrustworthy.

Comment: Try `print(os.getenv('APPDATA')==os.getenv('APPDATA').strip())`.

Comment: Don't know if it's relevant, but on my Windows computer the only thing in my `C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming` directory is other subdirectories — there are no files of any kind (and yes, I have show hidden and system files enabled).

Comment: @martineau same here, except for the file that I created there trying to reproduce the duplicate problem.  And it was more than a couple of days ago, because my file is dated 2021-07-20.  I'm on Windows 7 though, that might make a difference.

Comment: Make a [mcve].  After I added `import os` and removed the reference to `providersPath`, the code worked, the file was created, and I could see it in Explorer.   Myabe you've left out other code as well. The `attrib` wasn't needed, because the file only had the `A` (archive) bit set.

Comment: @CodeMed BTW, "a human user is not able to view the terraformRC file when looking for it in APPDATA using Windows Explorer" isn't a useful data point given that the file (somehow) started off with the hidden and/or system attributes. (Why does it have those attributes at all?)

Comment: @jamesdlin the default separator for `print` is space.

Comment: Try putting a `sleep(60)` just before opening the file for read.  Maybe something in your system is monitoring that directory and deleting anything that pops up.

Comment: @CodeMed that’s not what I was referring to. `print('a ',b)` will adds a space between the two items, which is why your prints have two spaces, and explains what @janesdlin pointed out

Comment: Do you have the same issue with any directory? E.g. "C:\Users\youruser\Documents"?

Comment: No, Your code worked for me in APPDATA and the file was visible in Explorer with only the A attribute.  There's something else going on that we can't repeat.

Comment: Use a tool like [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to watch the file accesses.  It really doesn't make sense that python can write and read the file but os.system with a full path can't find it.

Comment: Filter on Process=attrib.exe would be a place to start

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235855/discussion-between-mark-tolonen-and-codemed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you have installed Python from the Microsoft Store. Store apps are Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps and redirect AppData storage on a per-user basis to a unique user-specific area that a native app such as `attrib` is unaware of. For more information see [UWP - store and retrieve settings and other app data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data).

I recommend uninstalling the UWP version of Python and installing an official native binary from python.org, which will work as you expect.

Comment: This solves the problem that was described in the OP.